# MBassador doesn't support interface messages

Tags: java, interface, interface-implementation

I'm using [mbassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador), and publishing to interfaces doesn't seem to work. Below is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) using JUnit. I would expect this program to print `hello world`, but it does not. However, if I change this line:

```
public void handleFoo(FooInterface f) {
```

to this:

```
public void handleFoo(FooImpl f) {
```

The program works perfectly. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Note: `public void handleFoo(Object o)` also works.

```
import net.engio.mbassy.bus.BusConfiguration;
import net.engio.mbassy.bus.MBassador;
import net.engio.mbassy.listener.Handler;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MBassadorTest {
    @Test
    public void testMBassador() {
        MBassador<FooInterface> bus = new MBassador<>(BusConfiguration.Default());
        bus.subscribe(this);
        FooInterface myFoo = new FooImpl();
        bus.publish(myFoo);
    }

    public static interface FooInterface {
        String doSomething();
    }

    public static class FooImpl implements FooInterface {
        public String doSomething() {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }

    @Handler(rejectSubtypes = false)
    public void handleFoo(FooInterface f) {
        System.out.println(f.doSomething());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is now fixed in 1.1.7. Check it out and report back, if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of MBassador and it's true what durron597 says. The missing recognition of interfaces is a bug (a sloppy one,I admit) but it's easy to fix. It is already fixed in my codebase and I am currently including some more tests for it. Because I want to include more bugfixes, the release is still pending but it won't take more than some days.

I apologize for any inconvenience...

Comment: bennidi, I submitted a pull request for this last night :)

Comment: Oh, haha, my pull request doesn't work anyway. Still, my test case and the other fix might be helpful :)

Comment: Ah, Just looked at your commit, you fixed the other issue I fixed too. Still my test case may be useful :)

Comment: Hey bennidi, there was a problem with the git merging, I fixed it for you and improved the test case

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I included your test case in a different location. I will rewrite parts of the test infrastructure in the next days and publish the next release on Sunday. Stay tuned...

Comment: No problem, did you notice that I changed the `getSuperclasses` `Collection` to a `HashSet` because there is an obscure case where you can get duplicate interfaces if two classes in the hierarchy implement the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, this is a bug. It should be fixed in version 1.1.7 according to the author.

https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador/issues/31